# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str (works OK in VS Code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

The following python works in VSCode on Windows 10, but errors with,

```
userLookup = next(item for item in userData["data"] if item["user_name"] == key)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

in CLI Ubuntu 16.04. Both are running Python 3.7. I don't understand why this is. There are plenty of descriptions of this error out there, but I want to understand why the code works on one platform and not the other.

**Code description:**

The purpose of the code is to summaries which users have edited which articles (build a list of pages each has edited) and then look up the user's email address from their meta data.

There are 2 json files containing data dumped from mediawiki:

1. wikiPageAuthors.json - List of wiki pages and who last edited them
2. ew_user.json - List of wiki users.

**editorList.py:**

```
import json

class my_dictionary(dict): 

    # __init__ function 
    def __init__(self): 
        self = dict() 

    # Function to add key:value 
    def add(self, key): 
        self[key] = [] 


userList = my_dictionary() 

with open('wikiPageAuthors.json') as json_file:
    articleData = json.load(json_file)

with open('ew_user.json') as json_file:
    userData = json.load(json_file)

# Summaries all the articles based on last editor username
for page in articleData['query']['pages']:
    pageTitle = page['title']

    for metatag in page['revisions']:
        pageAuthor = metatag['user']

    if pageAuthor in userList:
        userList[pageAuthor].append(pageTitle)
    else:
        userList.add(pageAuthor)
        userList[pageAuthor].append(pageTitle)

# Send an email to each user telling them which articles they last edited/need to review.

for key,val in userList.items():
    # Look up the user's email address
    userLookup = next(item for item in userData["data"] if item["user_name"] == key)
    toAddr = userLookup['user_email']
```

**ew_user.json:**

```
{
"type": "table",
"name": "ew_user",
"database": "wiki_db",
"data": [
    {
    "user_id": "3",
    "user_name": "User1",
    "user_real_name": "User Number 1",
    "user_email": "User1@example.com"
    },
    {
    "user_id": "4",
    "user_name": "User2",
    "user_real_name": "User Number 2",
    "user_email": "User2@example.com"
    },
    {
    "user_id": "5",
    "user_name": "User3",
    "user_real_name": "User Number 3",
    "user_email": "User3@example.com"
    }
    ]
}
```

**wikiPageAuthors.json:**

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "warnings": {
      "allpages": {
        "*": "\"gaplimit\" may not be over 5000 (set to 50000) for bots or sysops."
      }
    },
    "query": {
      "pages": [
        {
          "pageid": 3893,
          "ns": 0,
          "title": "Page title 1",
          "revisions": [{ "user": "User1", "timestamp": "2015-11-10T16:33:09Z" }]
        },
        {
          "pageid": 7463,
          "ns": 0,
          "title": "Page title 2",
          "revisions": [
            { "user": "User2", "timestamp": "2017-09-26T13:10:56Z" }
          ]
        }
    ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: no issues.. its working in env Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: are you sure the code is exactly the same? This should work on ubuntu as well

Comment: The only difference is I've removed user's actual details from the json files.

Comment: I had to go as far as compiling Python 3.7 on ubuntu as it wasn't available on the default sources. Could I have missed something in the build options?

Comment: I just copy/pasted the exact python code above into my Ubuntu env and it still fails with the same error.

Comment: can you check what variable is seen as a list and raises the error?

Comment: I tried running the code on another Windows box and it's fine. So there is something screwie with my Ubuntu env. I'll post any news when I have it.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the data objects that you are getting from your JSON files to see the exact difference? And then read the files and printed out their contents to make sure they are the same JSON?